How to reload single systemd service to apply new settings at runtime
I have a use case where I use systemd api to enforce resource limits for systemd service. I create drop-files/unit files under service.d/ directory in the vm and run the systemctl daemon-reload cmd to apply new settings to my service at run time but it's affecting all services which are in the machine. This global command which runs in our service makes the changes for other services without consent of the owner/user/other services and also creates problems since it may change settings in other services. Are there any options available to reload only one service(unit) for running service(without restart)?
I researched systemctl doc, nothing promising. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html

For me it is not clear if you working on services or the systemd service. What means "_but it's affecting all services which are in the machine. _", because, if there is no change how can they be affected and by what? "I researched systemctl doc", maybe proceed further with What does systemctl daemon-reload do?

Yes I'm working on systemd service. There may be a change for other services but running daemon-reload in my script shouldn't be the cause for other services. I want to do it for service I'm responsible
